# Thread sleep does not continue execution after timeout

Tags: c++, command-line, thread-sleep

Why does thread block?

Hello i am trying to pause a thread for a given number of seconds.I am running the program from the command line.
The program enters the "sleep" but does not print anything , until i press `CTRL+C` at which point it prints everything it had to print in bulk.Why does it work in the background ?Why does it not print to the console after each `sleep_for`?

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>

#include<chrono>

#include<thread>

#include<string>

#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    std::cout<<"Started daemon..."<<std::endl;

    std::string hostString(argv[1]);
    std::cout<<"HostName:"<<hostString<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Port:"<<atoi(argv[2]);
    int i=0;

    while(true){
        std::cout<<"Iterations:"<<i;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
    if(i++>10000) i=0;

    }

    return 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many output operations are buffered.  That is they will wait to actually write to the string until they fill up the buffer.  This means that there can be a delay between when you tell it o print and when it actually does.

To fix this you can use the `flush` stream manipulator to force the contents to be written.  That would make your code look like

```
while(true){
    std::cout<<"Iterations:"<<i << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
    if(i++>10000) i=0;
}
```

If your stream is line buffered then you could also just print a newline like

```
while(true){
    std::cout<<"Iterations:"<<i << "\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
    if(i++>10000) i=0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Output to `std::cout` is, generally speaking, line buffered meaning nothing will appear at the console until either a newline is written or the buffered data reaches a certain size.  Try...

```
std::cout << "Iterations: "<< i << "\n";
```

Or, force a flush with...

```
std::cout << "Iterations: "<< i << std::flush;
```

Comment: But i have used `std::endl` is it not the same thing?

Comment: But you haven't used `std::endl` for the output within the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` is a buffered stream. That means whatever you write to that stream first goes into an internal buffer. That buffer is only emptied out ("flushed") when the runtime/system decides to do so. This is done mainly for performance reasons. It allows the runtime/system to not do tons of tiny I/O operations all the time, which would incur quite some overhead, but wait until enough output has accumulated so that expensive I/O can be done in larger batches.

You can call the `flush()` method to explicitly force the stream to be flushed or "output" `std::flush` to the stream:

```
std::cout << "bla" << std::flush
```

If you want to flush after each line, use `std::endl`, which outputs a newline character and also flushes.